# Cross check my code (Motion detector using Raspberry pi)

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

The buzzer is not stop buzzing eventhough I gave a 2 sec sleep and tell me how to stop duplicating the same statement inside the for loop

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO 
import time

sensor=13
buzzer=26

GPIO.setwarning(False)
GPIO.cleanup()
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(sensor,GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(buzzer,GPIO.OUT)

print("Initializing PIR sensor...")
     
time.sleep(2)

print("PIR ready...")
print("")

def infinity():

while True: yield
for i in infinity():
     pass 
     if GPIO.input(sensor)==True:

          GPIO.output(buzzer,GPIO.HIGH)
          time.sleep(2)
          print("Motion Detected")

     else:

          GPIO.output)buzzer,GPIO.LOW)
          print("Motion not detected")
          time.sleep(2)
```

"Neglect if you see any typo so small mistake because I can't copy the code from VNC instead I typed it"

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, please do make sure that the code you provide is free of typos. And valid to the best of your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

To infinitely check for motion and print `"Motion Detected"` only the first time motion is detected simply use a `detected` flag:

```
def infinity():
    detected = False
    while True:
         if GPIO.input(sensor) == True:
              GPIO.output(buzzer, GPIO.HIGH)
              if not detected:
                  print("Motion Detected")
                  detected = True
              time.sleep(2)
              GPIO.output(buzzer, GPIO.LOW)
```

However, imagine you were to detect motion once, and two seconds later the motion was not detected any longer. If the motion was then detected again, say, 10 seconds later, I suspect you'd want it to print `"Motion Detected"` again. So to print `"Motion Detected"` only every time the motion is detected after it was previously not detected, you'd want to use this code:

```
def infinity():
    detected = False
    while True:
         if GPIO.input(sensor) == True:
              GPIO.output(buzzer, GPIO.HIGH)
              if not detected:
                  print("Motion Detected")
                  detected = True
              time.sleep(2)
              GPIO.output(buzzer, GPIO.LOW)
         else:
             detected = False
```

Thus resetting `detected` flag every time the motion is not detected.

Comment: Sir How to stop duplicating the statement under the for loop

Comment: Do you mean you do not want the `"Motion Detected"` printed? I do not understand what your intentions are. With this code the behaviour should be: check if motion is detected. If so the buzzer activates and ``"Motion Detected"`` is printed to output, then the program pauses for 2 seconds. After two seconds the buzzer is deactivated and motion is checked for again. If motion is detected, the buzzer activates again and ``"Motion Detected"`` is printed again... and so on. Is it behaving like this? What would you like it to do instead?

Comment: Yes, you are right.. For first time the sensor detects some motion it will print "motion Detected" and second time, if the sensor detects it, will print the same but I want to print the statement "Motion Detected" for just one time even though the sensor detects motions repeatedly. Hope you got my doubt

Comment: @srivenky I edited the solution. Please don't forget to accept and upvote it if it worked for you, or comment here under to clarify or point out mistakes.

Comment: Can you give your contact number! because the program is not working or you can contact me, myself srivenky from INDIA contact me through whatsapp: 7010307722. I upvoted it.